# Change button layout in JOptionPane.showOptionDialog()

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

I am working on a program that has the user choose from a list of commands. My program has several commands, and JOptionPane.showOptionDialog() displays them horizontally.

[image: GIU]

As you can see, the window is wider than my screen. I'd like to make it to where there are two rows of buttons instead of one, that way the user can see all of the options.

How exactly would one do this?

Here is my code:

```
public int getCommand (String[] commands) {
    
    return JOptionPane.showOptionDialog
            (null,
                    "Choose an option below", // Prompt message
                    windowTitle, // Window title
                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION, // Option type
                    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, // Message type
                    null, // Icon
                    commands, // List of commands
                    commands[commands.length - 1]);
}
```

Comment: Don't use JOptionPane if you need greater complexity in your dialog. Intead, create and display a modal JDialog.

Answer (score 3):

The layout of the option pane is controlled internally, and there are no methods to directly control the layout of the buttons.

So, the proper solution is to just create a custom modal JDialog that displays the components based on your requirements.

However, if you really want to use the JOPtionPane functionality then you would need to:

1. create the JOptionPane as a Swing component and then change the layout manager of the panel containing the buttons.
2. add the JOptionPane to a JDialog and implement the standard option pane functionality manually.

The first step is demonstrated below:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SSCCE extends JPanel
{
    public SSCCE()
    {
        String[] commands = {"1", "2", "3", "4","5", "6", "7", "8"};

        JOptionPane op = new JOptionPane
        (
            "Choose an option below", // Prompt message
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, // Message type
            JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION, // Option type
            null, // Icon
            commands, // List of commands
            commands[commands.length - 1]
        );

        java.util.List<JButton> buttons = SwingUtils.getDescendantsOfType(JButton.class, op, true);
        Container parent = buttons.get(0).getParent();
        parent.setLayout( new GridLayout(2, 0, 5, 5) );

        add(op);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new SSCCE(), BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater( () -> createAndShowGUI() );
    }
}
```

The above code searches for the buttons that have been added to the option pane and then finds the parent container and changes the layout manager of the container to be a GridLayout. You will also need the [SwingUtils](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/13/swing-utils/) class.

To implement the second step you will need to `Read the API for the JOptionPane`. It contains the code necessary add the code to a JDialog and implement the option pane functionality.

Comment: Glad it helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark (beside the answer) so people know the problem has been solved.